# jQuery does not recognize PHP generated child element when clicked

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am working on a website on which I have to display buttons based on database content. Clicking these buttons should then send a request to the database and reload the content of the page appropriately.

Everything is done with Ajax and jQuery by executing PHP scripts. 
I can generate the buttons, but jQuery does not trigger when they are clicked.

**It seems that jQuery detects a click on the div containing the buttons but not on the buttons themselves.**

I was told that it may be **because the jQuery script is loaded before the page is updated with the new HTML content.**

This is the div container for all the choice buttons:

```html
<div id = "choices">
     <!-- Choices button will be displayed here -->
</div>
```

Here's the PHP code creating the HTML for the buttons:

```php
echo " <button class = 'choice' id = \"$id\">
        $content
      </button> ";
```

This code is loaded in the previous #choices div by this jQuery code :

```
$.post("php_script/getChoices.php", 

       function(result){
        $("#choices").html(result);

       });
```

Pretty basic, and the expected (and actual) output on the webpage is :

```html
<div id = "choices">

     <button class = 'choice' id = "1">
        Yes.
     </button>

     <button class = 'choice' id = "2">
        No.
     </button>

</div>
```

But when I write this :

```
$(".choice").click(function());
```

It never triggers, no matter how basic the function. 
However, having another event to interact with the buttons is possible.
For example, the code below does hide the buttons when the #choices div is clicked.

```
$("#choices").click(function(){
      $(".choice").hide(); 
});
```

In order to understand the problem, I wrote this jQuery script that print the content of the element that was clicked on the console.

```
$("*").on('click', function(event){

    event.stopPropagation();
    console.log('Clicked: ' + $(this).html());

});
```

And when I click on a button, it always returns the whole #choices div instead of just the content of the button.

As I said, I think this is because I am trying to interact with HTML elements that were added after the jQuery script was loaded (it is written in the  section of my page).

**Is my assumption correct and what should I do in order to trigger an action when the button themselves are clicked ?**

Comment: Use *delegation* `$('#choices').on('click', 'button', handler);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always target the document to trigger dynamically created elements:

```
$(document).on('click', '.choice', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //stop default behaviour
    var id = this.id; //get element ID
    $(this).hide(); //hide element
});
```

Comment: Works perfectly for detecting the clicks on .choice.
Though to get the id the correct syntax is `var id = $(this).attr("id")`.

Comment: You're right, I updated it to a working version. Your syntax also works.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned you can use event delegation

```
$(function(){
    $("#choices").on("click", "button", function(){
        alert("clicked");
    });
});
```

Or manually bind the event handler when you add the new buttons

```
// called each time new buttons are added
function bindOnClick(){
    $("#choices").off();
    $("#choices").on("click", "button", function(){
        alert("clicked");
    });
}

$(function(){
     // called once when dom is ready
     bindOnClick();
});
```

If you don't call off you will bind the `onclick` event to the same element more than once.